# Apache block external access for all files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vps

I've a VPS and I want to try to deny access to all files on my website, except for the index, images and pdf files.

I'm using this .htaccess file:

```
 <Files ~ "^.*">
  Deny from all
 </Files>

<Files ~ "^index\.php|css|js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.gif">
 Allow from all
</Files>
```

Is this the right way to do what I want? I noticed that if I write **www.mysite.com/image.jpg** I can access to the image, but if I write **www.mysite.com/style.css** I can't access it and it's the behaviour that I want.

But if I use a website downloader like **DarcyRipper** I can still download the whole site. Can't I block all the external request to access to a certain file?

**EDIT:**
I just checked: if I write www.mysite.com/js/script.js I can access it. But if I configure apache in order to deny all the access to the **JS** directory, the site can't load the script.

Is really impossible to block all the request from the outside but allow all the request done by the website?

Comment: All directives apply to any request, no matter what user agent is used. Most likely, there's something else going on or DarcyRipper downloads only part of the site.

Comment: I checked and DarcyRipper is downloading all the part of my website.

Anyway, my htaccess is the right one to deny access for a website?

Comment: According to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html, `Allow` and `Deny` are deprecated, even though they still work with current Apache. As always there's more than one way to reach a goal.

Comment: I just checked: if I write www.mysite.com/js/script.js I can access it. But if I configure apache in order to deny all the access to the **JS** directory, the site can't load the script.

Is really impossible to block all the request from the outside but allow all the request done by the website?

Comment: There's no way regarding Javascript, because any Javascript `<script>` is loaded by the user agent ("from outside") and not from inside. Your web application, e.g. PHP scripts, can always access all files, because such script accesses are not passed through Apache's access rules.